# How to take photos using one phone's camera and second phone's handling using Bluetooth?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I am Smit Patel and developing a android application for my final year project in college.

I have to android mobiles i want to use my one phone's camera without touching it only Bluetooth is on. now i use second phone with Bluetooth on and i want to handle my first phone's camera and showing that photo to my second one.

Any buddy has idea about this? please help me guys...

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you can remotely control another phones System app using just Bluetooth. These are all very sensitive things which if given access to cause Havoc in a smartphone. You first need to understand why **security** is of prime importance. A hacker would love it if he could do this. He could access sensitive data by just turning on his bluetooth! So kindly change your project to something a bit more secure.

Comment: Thanks for guidance i will take care about that and create it more secured.